# Can't get Engagement Split to select the right link click

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We have an email which has the following two links (simple survey):

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://our-site.com/?a=y">Satisfied</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://our-site.com/?a=n">Not Satisfied</a></li>
</ul>
```

in its HTML body. That email is sent to a DE from JB and we use an Engagement Split some time after the send to check is the "satisfied" link was click. If not, we use another Engagement Split to if the "Not Satisfied" link was.

This is shown on the JB canvas below :

[image]

Of course, waiting time are reduced for testing purposes, and further actions are removed for clarity.

We are facing the following: whatever link is clicked, the "satisfied" path is taken.

Ant idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Engagement Splits based on link clicks rely on domain + slug as a criteria. This means, regarding the click `https://our-site.com/?a=y` is the same as `https://our-site.com/?a=n`

You should change your logic here, and make two distinct target pages, with two different slugs (or use http redirects on those pages to your root page with the parameters if you wish)

The following is a working example :

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://our-site.com/a">Satisfied</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://our-site.com/b">Not Satisfied</a></li>
</ul>
```